# Equality of inner product of outerproducts of vector with itself d-times and the d-th power of the inner product of the two vectors

Tags: inner-products, tensor-products, tensors, outer-product

Suppose $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$,

proof that $\left\langle\mathbf{a}^{\otimes d}, \mathbf{b}^{\otimes d}\right\rangle=\langle\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}\rangle^{d}$

where $\mathbf{a}^{\otimes d}=\underbrace{\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{a} \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathbf{a}}_{d \text { times }} \quad$.

So when I try to prove this, I get from the left side

$\left\langle\mathbf{a}^{\otimes d}, \mathbf{b}^{\otimes d}\right\rangle=\sum_{i_{1}=1}^{n} \sum_{i_{2}=1}^{n} \cdots \sum_{i_{d}=1}^{n} a_{i_{1}} a_{i_{2}} \cdots a_{i_{d}} b_{i_{1}} b_{i_{2}} \cdots b_{i_{d}}$

and for the right side

$\langle\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}\rangle^{d}= (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})^d$ .

Does anyone know how to te reach an equality from here?
Thank you.

Comment: This is just multiplying out brackets.

Comment: But how do you do this for a general power? By induction?

Comment: Yes that should work - induction on $d$.